# Unable to find entry in maximo anywhere screen

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I added a `field` in `listtext` in the actual material details view, but I am not able to see it in screen.

Can you let me know how to add it?

Comment: could you put the XML here for the View ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   1.Make sure that you are adding in the correct view
   2.you have to add new row on  ActualMaterialListItem.xml i add the code below 
   3.in app.xml theirs layoutInsertAt set it to layoutInsertAt="item3"
    4.build and deploy 










 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout id="ActualMaterialListItem" width="100">
        <row id="row_0">
            <column columnid="item1" id="item1_column"/>    
        </row>
        <row id="row_1">
            <column colspan="10" columnid="item2" id="item2_column"/>
            <column colspan="2" columnid="item3" halign="right" id="item3_column"/>

        </row>
        <row id="row_2">
            <column colspan="12" columnid="item3" id="item3_column"/>


        </row>
    </layout>
```

Comment: Actually that's detail view not list view.